# Input:- I Love India Output:- I1 Love4 India5

Tags: java, c

What I'm doing wrong here in this code? 
Take input as a one string.than Print the length of each word. 
for example, the length of i is 1 and length of Love is 4 so print the length after the each word.

## include

## include

```
int main()
{
    int i,n,count=0;
    char str[20];
    gets(str);
    n=strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(str[i]==" "){
            printf("%d",count);
            count=0;
        }else{
            printf("%c",str[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: don't use the gets it s too dangerous use fgets instead

Comment: `if(str[i]==" ")` should be `if(str[i] == ' ')`. In the former case, you are comparing a character and a string literal. The second one compares two characters which is what you want. Compiling with warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra`) would've been helpful in spotting the error. Also, as mentioned in the above comment, never use `gets`.

Comment: @ChrisTurner I am getting output same as a input.

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues in the code:

- Comparing a character with a string literal.
- No space after printing a particular word and its length.
- For the last word, the comparison has to be with a null-terminator.
- Not taking the null-terminator into account in the condition check of the `for` loop.

Making these changes, you will get the required output.

[Demo here.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IkxvCkfTSUDswfiY)

**Note:** `gets` is deprecated and considered dangerous to use. Use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The line `if(str[i]==" "){` is wrong.
`" "` is a *string* and it consists of two bytes: the space character and a terminating NUL character.
You should use `if(str[i]==' '){` instead.
`' '` is a *character* and you should compare it with `str[i]`, which is also a character.

Also, it seems you forgot to print a space character after the numbers.

One more point is that you should print the length of the last word
even if there isn't a space character after the last word.

By the way, you shouldn't use `gets()`,
which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and deleted from C11.
You should use `fgets()`, which takes buffer size, instead.
`fgets()` saves newline characters read to the buffer while `gets()` doesn't,
so you should remove the newline characters if you don't want them.

An example of corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n,count=0;
    char str[20 + 1]; // allocate one more character for a newline character
    char* lf; // for searching for a newline character
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin); // use fgets() instead if gets()
    if ((lf = strchr(str, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0'; // remove a newline character if one exists
    n=strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){ // change < to <= for processing the terminating NUL character
        if(str[i]==' ' || str[i]=='\0'){ // compare with a character, not a string
            if (count>0) printf("%d",count); // avoid duplicate printing for duplicate space characters
            if(i+1<n) printf(" "); // print a space if the string continues
            count=0;
        }else{
            printf("%c",str[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```